# Google Sheets: Sheets as filtered views of data

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a financial spreadsheet that has an `All Transactions` sheet, which contains entries from multiple people. I would like to also have have dedicated sheets for each person (`John's Transactions`, `Jane's Transactions`), where they can see and edit the categories for their own expenses.

I know I can use a filter to accomplish this but only one filter can be applied at a time.

Is there any way to create a duplicate view of a sheet where I can show a subset of entries, but changes made to one will also change the other?

[Here is my example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gzp1RuufY9NHe_GBJLOMYP6v1_RMXb6nljlYfYMPtUc/edit#gid=1343063356)

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal from your question. So can I ask you about the detail of your goal? For example, when the basic filter is used, it can be reflect for each sheet. How about this? I also apologize for my poor understanding.

Comment: Have you already tried [tag:google-sheets-filter-view]s?

Comment: Documentation on Filter Views complementing the above comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en